# mysql query with start and end dates on individual rows

Tags: php, mysql, date, do-while

I have a data driven banner system which runs pretty well.

It runs off two tables

**banner_frames** 
This contains the individual rows for all banner frames and includes image, text and frame layout information.

**banner_frameset**
This contains the grouping information for which banner_frames row to bring in to the query as comma separated value.

There is a php variable `$bannerpageid` which if is set on a  page runs this query.

```
mysql_select_db($database_banners, $banners);
$query_banner_frameset = "SELECT banner_frameset.*, banner_frames.* 
FROM banner_frameset, banner_frames 
WHERE banner_frameset.bp_ID = $bannerpageid 
AND FIND_IN_SET(banner_frames.bf_ID, banner_frameset.bp_frames) 
AND banner_frames.bf_live = 1 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(banner_frames.bf_ID, banner_frameset.bp_frames)";
$banner_frameset = mysql_query($query_banner_frameset, $banners) or die(mysql_error());
$row_banner_frameset = mysql_fetch_assoc($banner_frameset);
$totalRows_banner_frameset = mysql_num_rows($banner_frameset);
```

I would like to modify the query to include an optional start date and/or expiry date for each frame row to only show affected frames if the current date/time is less than or greater than the entry set in any banner frame row.

The banner_frame columns for start date and expiry date are:
`bf_datestart` and `bf_dateexpire`

What I want to achieve is to pull in all the `banner_frames.bf_ID` listed in `banner_frameset.bp_frames` and  either omit or get a banner frames row dependant on if  either or both the start date and expiry date are set, while still retrieving all the other rows where either/or both the start or expiry are set to NULL

What is the most efficient way to execute this query, can the above query be modified or do I need to run it as a separate if statement before my do/while loop?

I hope this makes sense.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause including the start and end dates as variables, but initialize the start and end dates to the [min/max mysql supports](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for whatever date type you are using.  By default, the query would still run as normal since the default dates would be all-inclusive.  Change the start/end date variables as needed.